# Dynamically Creating Multiple <section> with Different Heights According to Input

Tags: jquery, html, css, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am creating `<section>` dynamically through a template by using Backbone.js, underscore.js, jQuery, .CSS, and HTML.

What I would like it to do is whenever a user types a value or uses the slider, information gets stored with backbone.js and then get loaded with the template below. `<section>` will be created with the specified height. That be said, I need to assume each `<section>` has different heights regardless of the content.

[This is a screenshot of what I currently have with all sections having the same height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ1i3.png)

This is the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="section-template">
       <section class="view">
              <label><%- height %></label>
              <label><%- color %></label>
       </section>
</script>
```

I have tried this in jQuery but obviously it did not work because this applies to all `<section>`.

CSS:

```
section {
    height: 200px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
          range: "max",
          min: 50,
          max: 500,
          value: 300,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            $('section').css('height', ui.value);
          }
  });
```

My question is what is the best technique in creating `<section>` dynamically with different heights? Preferably not needing to use any plugins.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on this and looking for alternatives today. However, after talking to a coworker, we have finally found a solution to my question. Here I will not explain how Model, View, and Collection will work together but simply a technique/trick to dynamically create section tags in .CSS so that each `<section>`can have a different height.

First, I create a unique numerical id by having a global variable in JavaScript:

```
var counter = 0;
```

Whenever a user inputs a value to specify a new `<section>` height, the variable increases by 1 and then create a model in a function inside `Backbone.View.extend()`:

```
counter++; //1

Sections.create({height: h, id: counter}); //create a model in Collection with the attributes where h = 500 and counter = 1 in this case
```

I then write to .CSS to specify the height for this model or `id='1'`in this case:

```
$('#section-'+counter).css('height', h);
```

Which gives me this in .CSS when a model is created:

```
#section-1 {
    height: 500;
}
```

Now to the template I add `id=section-<%- id %>` inside `<section>`:

```
<script type="text/template" id="section-template">
    <section class="view" id=section-<%- id %>>
          <label><%- height %></label>
    </section>
</script>
```

As you may have guessed, `id: counter` will be loaded into the template every time a model is created, giving it a unique id.

It would look like this where height = 500 and id = 1:

```
<section class="view" id="section-1">
        <label>500</label>
</section>
```

So when the next model (or `<section>`) is created where height = 1020 and id = 2, it would look like this:

```
<section class="view" id="section-2">
        <label>1020</label>
</section>
```

You can imagine now each `<section>` has its own height on HTML because it has a dedicated id tag and will only call the same id tag in .CSS.

I hope this helps.